# Disintegration of Measures

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I was thinking about this exercise and I can't see how to end it. I'm sorry about the long post and thank you for the attention. Before asking the question, I need some background.

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space. If $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ are measurable partitions of $\Omega$ such that all elements of $\mathcal{Q}$ are subset of a element of $\mathcal{P}$. It's possible to give to each partition a structure of a probability space that comes from $\pi_C=\Omega \rightarrow C$, with $\pi_C(x)=$the element $A$ of $C$ such that $x\in A$, where $C\in\{\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}\}$, such that

i) The $\sigma$-algebra is:
$A\subset C$ is measurable iff $\pi_C^{-1}(A)\subset \Omega$ is measurable

ii) The measure in $C$ is given by $\hat{\mu}_C(A) = \mu(\pi_C^{-1}(A))$.

We say that a famyly $\{\mu_A: A \in C\}$ of probabylities in $\Omega$ is a disintegration with respect to the partition $C$ if

i) $\mu_A(A)=1$ for $\hat{\mu}_C$-almost $A\in C$.

ii) The map $\phi_{(C,E)}: C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi_{(C,E)}(A)=\mu_A(E)$ is measurable for all $E\subset \Omega$ measurable.

iii) $\mu(E)=\int_{C} \mu_A(E) d\hat{\mu}_C$

Here is the question: Consider the disintegration of $\mu$ with respect to $\mathcal{P}$ given by the family $\{\mu_P: P \in \mathcal{P}\}$. Let $\{\mu_{P,Q}: Q \subset P, Q\in\mathcal{Q}\}$ be a disintegration of $\mu_P$. Prove that $\{\mu_{P,Q}: Q\in\mathcal{Q}\}$ is a disintegration of $\mu$ with respect to $\mathcal{Q}$.

I got stuck in the 3rd part of the definition. Here is what I got
$$\mu(E)=\int_{\mathcal{P}} \mu_P(E) d\hat{\mu}_\mathcal{P} = \int_\mathcal{P} \left( \int_\mathcal{Q} \mu_{P,Q}(E) d\hat{\mu}_{P,\mathcal{Q}}\right) d\hat{\mu}_\mathcal{P}$$
and I can't manage to make someking of change of variables to get $\int_\mathcal{Q} \mu_{P,Q}(E) d\hat{\mu}_\mathcal{Q}$. Do you guys have anykind of hint? Any other approach or idea?

Comment: There might be some typos: $\pi_C:\Omega\to C$ instead of $\pi_C=C\to\Omega$? $\pi_C^{-1}(A)$  instead of $\pi_C(A)$? $\pi_C^{-1}(A)$  instead of $\pi_c^{-1}(A)$? $\phi_{(C,E)}(A)=\mu_A(E)$  (and probably $\phi_{C,E}(A)$, in fact) instead of $\phi_{(C,E)}=\mu_A(E)$? Later on, $\hat\mu_{P,\mathcal Q}$ should probably be $\hat\mu_{\mathcal Q}$.

Comment: They are all correct (and I will correct it as soon as possible) except for the last one. I'm not sure about it because I think that's the key to solve the problem! What we have is that we desintegrate each $\mu_P$ with respect to $\mathcal{Q}$. I think we have to understand the relation btw $\hat{(\mu_P)}_{\mathcal{Q}}=: \hat{\mu}_{P,\mathcal{Q}}$ and $\hat{\mu}_\mathcal{Q}$. Once we get this I think the calculus will folow in a natural way!